# Iterate over a list of Dictionaries where each dictionary has another dict in it

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries in this format

```
[ {"data" : {"a" : "x" , "b" : "y"}, "format" : "c"},  {"data" : {"p" : "e" , "q" : "f"}, "format" : "r"} ]
```

I need to extract the data dict separately and the format which is a string separately and print them. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

NOTE: The spaces don't exist in the original code. I just added them to make it more readable.
EDIT: Using Python 2.7 and need a solution for it.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.

Comment: use a for loop for i in a:
    print i['data']
    print i['format']

Comment: what is your desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a **[for Loop](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop)** to iterate over your list of dictionaries.:

**Example**:

```
a = [ {"data" : {"a" : "x" , "b" : "y"}, "format" : "c"},  {"data" : {"p" : "e" , "q" : "f"}, "format" : "r"} ]
for i in a:
    print "data", i['data']
    print "format", i['format']
```

**Result:**

```
data {'a': 'x', 'b': 'y'}
format c
data {'q': 'f', 'p': 'e'}
format r
```

Comment: Thanks!!! New to Python..so it's a tad bit confusing

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the list of dictionaries.  Below will return the data Value and the format value.  Then you can iterate over the result

`for item in listDict:
    print item.values()`

Comment: Thank You!! will try both the approaches